# Border-image property is not woking in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: firefox, css

Hi trying to figure out what's wrong in my code.

Everything works fine except for the border-image when comes to firefox.

Here's my code:

```
.header_holder{
        border-bottom-width:2px;
        -webkit-border-image:url("../img/assets/border-image.png") 0px 0px 2px 0px stretch;
        -moz-border-image:url("../img/assets/border-image.png") 0px 0px 2px 0px stretch;
        -ms-border-image:url("../img/assets/border-image.png") 0px 0px 2px 0px stretch;
        -o-border-image:url("../img/assets/border-image.png") 0px 0px 2px 0px stretch;
        border-image:url("../img/assets/border-image.png") 0px 0px 2px 0px stretch;
        position:fixed;
        z-index:999;
    }
```

Regards to those who can help...

Thanks!

Comment: What does *not working* mean?

Comment: Can you produce a jsfiddle that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frankly, it isn't working in any browsers, therefore the issue isn't necessarily specific to Firefox.

The syntax was incorrect, you *aren't* suppose to specify a measurement, in your case, `px`. Just omit the measurement and it should work as expected.

[**MDN Reference**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image) - Formal syntax:

```
<'border-image-source'> || <'border-image-slice'> [ / <'border-image-width'> | / <'border-image-width'>? / <'border-image-outset'> ]? || <'border-image-repeat'>
```

Here is the example they give:

```
.example { 
    border-image: url("/files/4127/border.png") 30 30 repeat;
}
```

Updated CSS:

```
.header_holder {
    border-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
    border-image: url("../img/assets/border-image.png") 0 0 2 2 stretch;
    -webkit-border-image: url("../img/assets/border-image.png") 0 0 2 2 stretch;
    -moz-border-image: url("../img/assets/border-image.png") 0 0 2 0 stretch;
    -ms-border-image: url("../img/assets/border-image.png") 0 0 2 0 stretch;
    -o-border-image: url("../img/assets/border-image.png") 0 0 2 0 stretch;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

It works in FF and other supported browsers now. [(example here)](http://jsfiddle.net/7GAYF/1/)

---

You may be interested in this helpful resource - http://border-image.com/

Comment: @JuliusRobles Can you please post a link to the page showing the problem?

Comment: Hi guys thank you for all your ideas and comments, really appreciate it! I solved that problem thanks!